# Issue with verifying password during user registration - hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it without making new column in DB. So I have a registration form with fields username, password, password2 (for verifying if both are matching) and other now not important fields. Also I have mapped class User with hibernate to my sql table and this method in controller which verifies the user input:

```
public ModelAndView addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
if(userService.correctInput(user))
        userService.addUser(user);
else ...
    }
```

Let me show you my problem:
if i want to verify input there must be password2 field in the form, otherwise i can't acces to that value after submiting the form. But then i need to have an attribute password2 in my mapped class User, but not mapped to my table, only simple attribute, that's working fine, but the problem is that i cant save user to my database if i have non-mapped attribute password2. Something like this:

```
...
@Column(name = "password")
    @Basic
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword2() {
        return password2;
    }

    public void setPassword2(String password2) {
        this.password2 = password2;
    }
...
```

if I want to save this, it throws an exceptions. I have 2 possible (but not smart) solutions for this: Althought first is smart, but I don't want to do it and it's already mentioned another column for password2 in my database, the second is another class (non-mapped) user with one more attribute for password2 and transforming from one to other - but that's wrong and very complicated practise. Do you have a good solution for this? without making new column in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `@Transient` annotation to tell Hibernate that the `password2` property shouldn't be persisted.